# Are sharding and normalization mutually exclusive?

Tags: database-design, scalability

I ran across a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217262/normalize-or-denormalize-in-high-traffic-websites) that made me wonder:  If you use a sharding approach to db scalability, does that mean the database is denormalized? Can you have a normalized, sharded database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The are not mutually exclusive.  Both are often used when scaling massive datasets, but one doesn't really have much to do with the other.  You can absolutely have a sharded, normalized database...or a denormalized, nonsharded database.

In sharding, you're just taking a given schema (normalized or not) and distributing it across a number of physical/logical data stores.  This allows, for example, you to have all your users with a particular characteristic (e.g., last name in 'A-D') to live on a given database instance.  Note that HOW you shard your database is a crucial decision and will be highly implementation dependent.

Denormalization, on the other hand, can be done with or without a sharded database and is intended to simply queries by reducing the joins/subqueries needed to answer a particular question.  Of course, then you would typically programmatically maintain data integrity.

Some good reading:

[Sharding theory & practice](http://highscalability.com/unorthodox-approach-database-design-coming-shard)

[Some highly-scalable database implementations 'in the wild'](http://www.slideshare.net/techdude/scalable-web-architectures-common-patterns-and-approaches/138)